# Performance Issues with Calculation during Turtle Procedure

Tags: netlogo

I am building a type of 'honey-bee' model, where the bees are turtle agents and the honey is a patch specific variable. In my model, each patch is assigned a value of 'honey-here' between 1-100 based on a specific distribution.

The model starts with the bees only being able to collect honey from flowers with honey = 1, for which they then receive 1 unit of honey in return. Before the bees can 'target' flowers with honey = 2, they need to occupy (i.e. a bee on a flower) X% of the total flowers with honey = 1. For example, I might require the bees to achieve 80% occupancy, which means if there are 10 flowers total with the variable honey = 1 then the bees need to occupy 8 of those flowers before they are allowed to start looking/targeting flowers with honey = 2. As each bee individually acts, the % occupancy value will change.

I'm having performance issues for the occupancy calculation. Ideally the calculation is updated within a turtle procedure as it needs to be applied to each turtle within the loop. Here's what I currently have to find the value of the variables I need to set current % occupancy before each bee is allowed to act:

```
ask bees
[           
;; set up variable based on ratio of number of turtles occupying target patch size against total number target patch size
;; note -- don't do this in one step to avoid divide by 0
let patch-count-current (count patches with [honey-here = bee-honey-target-size])
;; don't want number of bees, want number of unique patches
let patch-target-occupy count patches with [ (count bees-here > 0) and (honey-here = bee-honey-target-size) ] 
...
```

Later in the code, after checking to make sure patch-count-current isn't 0, I find my % occupancy via patch-target-occupy / patch-count-current

It turns out this is a very expensive hit on my processor performance. Especially as my number of bees grows, which is exponential in my model.

Is there a better way that won't cost me so much processor for each iteration of the loop?

Thanks!

-dp

Answer (score 1):

Given your response to StephenGuerin, you could manually track the counts with global variables. If there is only one `bee-honey-target-size` at a time, this is pretty simple. Just make a `patch-count-current` global and a `patch-target-occupy`. Then, increase them or decrease them as things change.

The Sandpile model (from the models library) uses this technique to keep track of the total amount of sand without having to iterate over the patches. Check out how the `total` global variable is used.

If you need to keep track of the counts for all `bee-honey-target-size`s at once, you could store a list of the counts in a global variable, where the index of the list corresponds to a value of `bee-honey-target-size`. This is much messier unfortunately, so you would have to write helper functions for sure.

Let me know if any of this needs clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Percentage occupancy is a property of the group and only needs to be calculated once per simulation step. Your performance hit is due to calculating occupancy for every bee in your simulation. The calculation for percentage occupancy for a given 'target-honey' could look like this:

```
to-report calc-occupancy [target-honey]
   report (sum [count turtles-here] of patches with [honey-here = target-honey]) / count turtles
end
```

Comment: Understood and agreed. In my simulation, I was wondering/hoping if there was a way to run this calculation throughout the turtle procedure to update with every individual turtle. But currently I've used a similar method to yours above to move this calculation to a group procedure. It's the only way my processor can handle. Thanks!